# PHP file_exists and unlink doesn't work ("No such file or directory")

Tags: php, warnings, file-exists, unlink

```
$path = "F:/www/__DADOS__/__SESSAO/__9987f2bfdfb80bce8fd72402887bb2c50a433ae0__E6nDSMnD7TCY5#47$BNCx0e#47$r#47$ByZJvcyMIazXSYWBWBXN5lgdZOd3Ps#47$ROrVSPl7QVQaCqfa2WezCauk#47$LVFyhgw==.meudominio.com.sessid"

file_put_contents($path, $texto);

unlink($path);
```

In the above code I get the warning **`No such file or directory`** in **`unlink($ path);`** and the file is not deleted, I also tried using **`file_exists`** to check the file before, and the return is: **`false`**.

The **`file_put_contents`** creates the file correctly (checked), even with the correct content. I can access the file through **`file_get_contents`**, but in time to delete or verify the existence get failure. Anyone have a clue?

The total size of `$path` is `241`.

The problem seems more delicate. The file name is formed by an **base64_encode**, the filename changes often, and I have about 10 files per execution. I can delete some, others not, issuing the warning described above. Can it be any character that is not to **unlink()** does not accept? I have some escape reserved characters such as **/\?%*:|"<>**. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename

I tried using hash (sha1, sha256 and sha512) instead of base64_encode, but the error persists.

Comment: you should use double Or single quotes around your string value `$path` `$path = "F:/www/__DADOS__/__SESSAO/__9987f2bfdfb80bce8fd72402887bb2c50a433ae0__E6nDSMnD7TCY5#47$BNCx0e#47$r#47$ByZJvcyMIazXSYWBWBXN5lgdZOd3Ps#47$ROrVSPl7QVQaCqfa2WezCauk#47$LVFyhgw==.meudominio.com.sessid"`

But are you sure that your file name is that long???, and contains `#` ???

Comment: forgiveness, she is already in quotes, just forgot to put them here, if we would not have an error, this line is not the case. Thank you. Any suggestions?

Comment: if said that you forget the `"` around your `$path` value and i guess that you have `;` at the end of this var definition as well but you forgot to write it here, then your code doesn't has any issue and the same var you are reading the file using it; you should be able to use it to delete the file "`unlink()`"

Comment: I have about 10 files per run, and it works in some and not in others. I infer that it is a problem with it, but not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `/` inside of `" "` so `/` char is not a normal character and it's usually used to escape special characters (*wen used inside of double quotation marks*), but if you want to ignore any `/` inside of your string value definition just use `//`
so the first forward slash will escape the second one and `PHP` will treat them as one slash
but don't forget to escape dollar sign (`$`) as well and all special chars or change your quotations from `"` to `'` then you don't have to change anything inside your string value:

```
<?php
$path = 'F:/www/__DADOS__/__SESSAO/__9987f2bfdfb80bce8fd72402887bb2c50a433ae0__E6nDSMnD7TCY5#47$BNCx0e#47$r#47$ByZJvcyMIazXSYWBWBXN5lgdZOd3Ps#47$ROrVSPl7QVQaCqfa2WezCauk#47$LVFyhgw==.meudominio.com.sessid';
//OR
$path = "F://www//__DADOS__//__SESSAO//__9987f2bfdfb80bce8fd72402887bb2c50a433ae0__E6nDSMnD7TCY5#47/$BNCx0e#47/$r#47/$ByZJvcyMIazXSYWBWBXN5lgdZOd3Ps#47/$ROrVSPl7QVQaCqfa2WezCauk#47/$LVFyhgw==.meudominio.com.sessid";

echo file_exists($path);//will return 1
//unlink($path);
?>
```

Comment: have you used `'` instead of `"` and the issue persist?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use ' instead of ", and also used // with ". The same I did with \ and \\, I am in windows environment (production).

Comment: actually if you used `'` instead of `"` you don't have to do anything else just make sure the file it's really exist there by browsing to the file location in your drive `F:\ ` if it's there then your issue is not related to this snippet

Comment: I wish it were so, it would be so easy to solve, but when I copy the path and paste in windows explorer, windows finds and opens the file. When I use file_get_contents it reads the file. That's why I'm finding it very strange. Because unlink() and file_exists() does not work?

Comment: ok can you try this:
`$path = 'F:\www\__DADOS__\__SESSAO\__9987f2bfdfb80bce8fd72402887bb2c50a433ae0__E6nDSMnD7TCY5#47$BNCx0e#47$r#47$ByZJvcyMIazXSYWBWBXN5lgdZOd3Ps#47$ROrVSPl7QVQaCqfa2WezCauk#47$LVFyhgw==.meudominio.com.sessid';`

Comment: if only to change the bar / to . I already did, and have also tried, including using \\.

Comment: Sorry but i'm sure your problem not related to this snippet, because it's working on my machine locally and on my testing hosting as well

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$path ="F:/www/__DADOS__/__SESSAO/__9987f2bfdfb80bce8fd72402887bb2c50a433ae0__E6nDSMnD7TCY5#47$BNCx0e#47$r#47$ByZJvcyMIazXSYWBWBXN5lgdZOd3Ps#47$ROrVSPl7QVQaCqfa2WezCauk#47$LVFyhgw==.meudominio.com.sessid"
```

Comment: forgiveness, she is already in quotes, just forgot to put them here, if we would not have an error, this line is not the case. Thank you. Any suggestions?

Comment: I use base64_encode, with appropriate substitutions based on [wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename).