# php open a .json string file and convert to array

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
<?php
$postcode=$_POST['script'];

// $myfile = file_get_contents("./aircondata/".$postcode.".json");
// echo $myfile;

$myfile = '{
  "1": { "Brand":"MITSUBISHI HEAVY INDUSTRIES, LTD.", "Model_No":"SRK20ZMXA-S / SRC20ZMXA-S", "C.Power_Inp_Rated":0.35, "H.Power_Inp_Rated":0.45, "KWH":1881.95, "Cost":564.585},
  "2": { "Brand":"MITSUBISHI HEAVY INDUSTRIES LTD.", "Model_No":"SRK20ZIX-S", "C.Power_Inp_Rated":0.35, "H.Power_Inp_Rated":0.45, "KWH":1881.95, "Cost":564.585},
  "3": { "Brand":"MITSUBISHI HEAVY INDUSTRIES LTD.", "Model_No":"SRK20ZJX-S", "C.Power_Inp_Rated":0.35, "H.Power_Inp_Rated":0.45, "KWH":1881.95, "Cost":564.585},
  "4": { "Brand":"TOSHIBA", "Model_No":"RAS-07PKVP-E/PAVP-E", "C.Power_Inp_Rated":0.355, "H.Power_Inp_Rated":0.44, "KWH":1908.835, "Cost":572.6505},
  "5": { "Brand":"CARRIER", "Model_No":"50PCH006", "C.Power_Inp_Rated":0.4, "H.Power_Inp_Rated":0.4, "KWH":2150.8, "Cost":645.24}
}';


$ac_decoded = json_decode($myfile, true);

echo $ac_decoded;
foreach ($ac_decoded as $key => $value) {
    if($key=="1"){
        echo $value["Brand"];

    }

}
echo "okay";

fclose($myfile);

?>
```

my problem is, this above code works when the json array is present in the same .php file, but the commented out code(using file_get_contents) won't work for json_decode, only works when echoed.
Please help... Thanks!!

To answer the suggestion from the first reply, the following is the `.json` file, not sure if the format is correct

```
'{
  "1": { "Brand":"MITSUBISHI HEAVY INDUSTRIES, LTD.", "Model_No":"SRK20ZMXA-S / SRC20ZMXA-S", "C.Power_Inp_Rated":0.35, "H.Power_Inp_Rated":0.45, "KWH":1881.95, "Cost":564.585},
  "2": { "Brand":"MITSUBISHI HEAVY INDUSTRIES LTD.", "Model_No":"SRK20ZIX-S", "C.Power_Inp_Rated":0.35, "H.Power_Inp_Rated":0.45, "KWH":1881.95, "Cost":564.585},
  "3": { "Brand":"MITSUBISHI HEAVY INDUSTRIES LTD.", "Model_No":"SRK20ZJX-S", "C.Power_Inp_Rated":0.35, "H.Power_Inp_Rated":0.45, "KWH":1881.95, "Cost":564.585},
  "4": { "Brand":"TOSHIBA", "Model_No":"RAS-07PKVP-E/PAVP-E", "C.Power_Inp_Rated":0.355, "H.Power_Inp_Rated":0.44, "KWH":1908.835, "Cost":572.6505},
  "5": { "Brand":"CARRIER", "Model_No":"50PCH006", "C.Power_Inp_Rated":0.4, "H.Power_Inp_Rated":0.4, "KWH":2150.8, "Cost":645.24}
}'
```

Comment: Code looks good. Double check the file contents are valid JSON. Or post the file contents here.

Btw, you might reconsider opening & reading file contents from a path inputted by a user without some kind of validation. Think about if somebody posted a value to 'script' that began with '../../'

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error or notice when you include the file?

Comment: $myfile = fopen("./aircondata/".$postcode.".json", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

Comment: the code works. can you dump the  $postcode variable ?

Comment: when i use the above code, it echoed "Resource id #3" and that is why i changed to "file_get_contents" which can echo the whole content of .json file.  I guess the file is correctly included.

Comment: @Christian, $postcode is from Google's voice recognition code, it is a string.  I var_dump $ac_decoded and result is NULL

Comment: @Aaron can u help me to check if the file contents can be considered as valid JSON? thank you..

Comment: I just want to be sure that the $postcode is populated and does not have any "empty" space. For example: if the value is "3021" double check that the path is correct "./aircondata/3021.json". Or you can hard code path  and try it

Comment: @Christian thank you, it should be with no spaces, i just checked with echo $postcode

Comment: Have you tried to use [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to debug? What does `json_last_error()` return after you decode the postcode json file content?

Comment: If you really do have single quotes before and after your `jSON` like in your example (the second one), then those need to be removed.

Comment: @KoalaYeung good suggestion thanks!        the code snippet and the result is sytax error: ----  case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';

Comment: the format of you json file is not correct. remove the single quote " ' "

Comment: @Rasclatt is right, the single quotes in the .json file need to be removed. That will raise the `malformed JSON` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference to my existing [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455188/php-file-exists-and-unlink-doesnt-work/18455527#18455527).. you have a syntax in `file_get_contents` call:

`$myfile = file_get_contents("./aircondata/".$postcode.".json");`

you have to escape special characters as follow:

`$myfile = file_get_contents(".//aircondata//".$postcode.".json");`

*P.S.: You have always keep an eye on the php error reporting which i think is not active in your server.*

**Update:**

Another possible reason might be the format of the JSON contents of the included file, please make sure you [validate the contents](http://jsonlint.com/).

if the data in that file really braced with single quotation mark then that is an invalid `JOSN` file.

Comment: after modifying this, it is not working still... but thanks!

Comment: the $ac_decoded array is still NULL so i can't echo any values from that array

Comment: What is the output of *var_dump($myfile);* ?

Comment: Hi @ash_8247 the main bug is for my .json file, as shown above..  but thank you all for helping :)